# Fill the hole in the image properly

Tags: java, opencv

I have to find out the contour of the image. After that, I want to find out how to fill in hole in the number characters, but not in the other space. The image is the following.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlLYE.jpg

Actually, if it is not possible, is there any other method for me to perform segmentation of this image by using openCV in java platform? I want the image contains the characters only. Thankyou.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY4Dh.png

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method (But I am not sure if it will work everywhere. Test it yourself)

NB: Code is in Python, I don't do Java, sorry about that :(

1. **Load the grayscale image**
2. **Apply Otsu's binarization**

> ```
> import cv2
> import numpy as np
> img = cv2.imread('test.png',0)
> ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
> ```

**Below is the thresholded image**:

[image]

Now you can try two methods:

3a. **Median Blurring with a 3x3 kernel**

> res = cv2.medianBlur(thresh,3)

**Result:**

[image]

3b. **Erosion with a 3x1 kernel (vertical)**. 3x1 because all the lines in your image are more-horizontal. It there are vertical lines in other images, you may need to take 3x3 kernel (not sure. Check it)

> ```
> kernel = np.ones((3,1))
> cls = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel)
> ```

If you think you are losing some parts of digits also, you can apply dilation after erosion, or replace everything with morphological opening function.

Result:

[image]

Finally, find contours. It will also pick up some noise left in the preprocessed image, but you can filter out them by checking their aspect ratio, area etc.

Comment: i want to know how to find out threshold value is 127, because i have a various image and i need to have the general function

Comment: answer modified. Answer modified. You pass just 0 there. Otsu will automatically find suitable threshold value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a not that complicated solution. Think about the vertical run length representation of the image: since you have only black and white there, you can think that each vertical line of the image is a list containing only 1(black pixel) and 0 (white pixel) so you will have for instace 01111111110000000000000111. This can be minimized if you will take only the lengths of each sublist containing only 1 or 0, so instead of 0000000001111111000111111111111 you will have 0 9 7 3 12, starts with 0 because let us say that you always start with the count of black pixels, and since there you don't have any black pixels at the begining you put a 0 (it will be much easier to work like this). After you have this reprezentation you take the maximal value for a white run (the run is actually that count of white or black pixels) and the minimal one and go throught all white runs. For each of them you see if the value is closer to the smallest white run, and if this is the case you just remove it.

This algorithm should work for the given image ;)